cannot insert custom data on drag-and-drop of vscode.TreeItem to editor

I need to drag a vscode.TreeItem (node) on the editor and need to insert some data  based upon node which is dragged.
To achieve this, I have followed sample - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/tree-view-sample/src/testViewDragAndDrop.ts
This sample inserts content of resourceUri property on vscode.TreeItem prefix with \

On handleDrag() method if we specify file uri to 'text/uri-list' MIME type (as shown in below code snippet) then drag and drop on editor opens new file as specified in file URI and
If we press shift key and drop then it inserts file uri path i.e. c:\office.txt rather than inserting content of file.


public async handleDrag(source: Node[], treeDataTransfer: vscode.DataTransfer, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Promise {
treeDataTransfer.set('application/vnd.code.tree.testViewDragAndDrop', new vscode.DataTransferItem(source));
let uri = vscode.Uri.parse("file:///C:/office/1.txt");
let dataTransferItem = new vscode.DataTransferItem(uri.toString());
treeDataTransfer.set('text/uri-list', dataTransferItem);
}

To insert custom data i have implemented one more interface vscode.DocumentDropEditProvider (code snippet shows). Can this be used to insert data for drag and drop of vscode.treeview node to editor? Documentation says it is used to drag and drop files

class FileNameListOnDropProvider implements vscode.DocumentDropEditProvider {
async provideDocumentDropEdits(
_document: vscode.TextDocument,
_position: vscode.Position,
dataTransfer: vscode.DataTransfer,
token: vscode.CancellationToken
): Promise<vscode.DocumentDropEdit | undefined> {
// Check the data transfer to see if we have dropped a list of uris
const dataTransferItem = dataTransfer.get(uriListMime);
if (!dataTransferItem) {
return undefined;
}
    // 'text/uri-list' contains a list of uris separated by new lines.
    // Parse this to an array of uris.
    const urlList = await dataTransferItem.asString();
    if (token.isCancellationRequested) {
        return undefined;
    }

    const uris: vscode.Uri[] = [];
    for (const resource of urlList.split('\n')) {
        try {
            uris.push(vscode.Uri.parse(resource));
        } catch {
            // noop
        }
    }

    if (!uris.length) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // Build a snippet to insert
    const snippet = new vscode.SnippetString();
    uris.forEach((uri, index) => {
        const name = path.basename(uri.path);
        snippet.appendText(`${index + 1}. ${name}`);
        snippet.appendTabstop();

        if (index <= uris.length - 1 && uris.length > 1) {
            snippet.appendText('\n');
        }
    });

    //return new vscode.DocumentDropEdit(snippet);
    return new vscode.DocumentDropEdit(`testing drag
    n drop` );
}

}
